# UITableView Delete button

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to replace the default delete buttons in editing style of UITableView with my own buttons. how to do it?

```
 -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
return @"title!";
}
```

this edits title of button .What about changing the color of button..
can anyone help me out

Comment: you can change test of delete button

Answer (score 0):

We can customize the default delete button in UITableView.But as per the IOS Human Interface guidelines your app may rejected by the apple if ur try to change that one.
You can refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html